# How do I declare process type with Procfile?

Tags: django, heroku, procfile

I am trying to build an app using Django & Heroku. I am following the steps found in this tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django

Here are my steps:

```
mkdir hellodjango && cd hellodjango
virtualenv venv --distribute
source venv/bin/activate
pip install django-toolbelt
django-admin.py startproject hellodjango .
```

I am then asked to create a so-called "Procfile":

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi
```

And have it "live at the root of the directory of my project". How do I do this (please excuse me if this seems a very straightforward problematic; I am new to all things programming and am finding the learning curve quite steep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create file with the name `Procfile` and simply paste `web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi` there.

So, for example, your git repository located here: `/Users/admin/git/hellodjango/`. Then, you need to place `Procfile` right in this directory.

```
cd /Users/admin/git/hellodjango/
touch Procfile
```

And open it with any text editor and paste `web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi`.

After you commit and push your changes to Heroku cloud, it will automatically detect application type declarated in `Procfile` and run it.